# Converting NSDictionary object to NSArray in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Hello Friends I have dictionary which contains one array SubItems out of 5 key/value pairs.
SubItem array also contains two dictionary. so I'm not getting how to get dictionary object to NSArray on certain condition.

```
simply means 
      if(true)
      {
         dictionary1
      }
      else
      {
        dictionary2
      }
```

And I want dictionary object to array in Object form not key/value pairs....

Here is dictionary :

```
{
    Name = "Verify Your Work Email ID";
    SubItems =     (
                {
            Name = "SubItem 0";
            cellHeight = "110.0";
            cellIdentifier = ExpandedCell;
            level = 1;
        },
                {
            Name = WorkEmailSendOTP;
            "New item" = cellHeight;
            cellHeight = "75.0";
            cellIdentifier = WorkEmailCell;
            level = 1;
        }
    );
    cellHeight = "65.0";
    cellIdentifier = Cell;
    level = 0;
}
```

Comment: You can get array from SubItems key, and then you can get object from index of array based on your condition.